# XMPP SSL Handshake failed

Tags: python, xmpp

I am having difficulty in establishing a connection  with XMPP (Prosody) . But if I use PSI it works fine and request for your suggestions.

Here is the code snippet of my python :

```
client = xmpp.Client(host)
client.connect(server=(host,port))
client.auth(username, passwd,resource='', sasl=1)
client.sendInitPresence()
```

In debug mode :

```
DEBUG: dispatcher  warn  Registering protocol "error" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams)
DEBUG: socket      sent  <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" to="localhost" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" >
DEBUG: socket      error Socket error while receiving data
                         Traceback (most recent call last):
                            File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 161, in receive
                            try: received = self._recv(BUFLEN)
                            error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
DEBUG: client      stop  Disconnect detected
DEBUG: socket      error Socket operation failed
                         Traceback (most recent call last):
                            File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 161, in receive
                            try: received = self._recv(BUFLEN)
                            error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
DEBUG: socket      error Socket error while receiving data
DEBUG: client      stop  Disconnect detected

**Prosody logs :** 
Oct 20 23:46:39 c2s94ba718      info    Client connected
Oct 20 23:46:39 c2s94ba718      info    Client disconnected: ssl handshake failed
Oct 20 23:46:39 c2s94ba718      info    Destroying session for (unknown) ((unknown)@(unknown))
Oct 20 23:48:57 c2s96052a0      info    Client connected
Oct 20 23:48:57 c2s96052a0      info    Client disconnected: ssl handshake failed
Oct 20 23:48:57 c2s96052a0      info    Destroying session for (unknown) ((unknown)@(unknown))
```

Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated. Aim is to connect to a XMPP server and join a MUC through python.

Comment: Which xmpp Python package are you using exactly?

Comment: Can you change the log level to debug for prosody and try connecting, and post the logs here?

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you are using Python 2.7, be sure you updated to the latest version (2.7.11) because there are some recently SSL changes that could break a LOT of code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Pidgin (libpurple 2.10.11) when I did not provide a certificate chain on the server-side.

I solved this by adding the CA-bundle (i.e. *intermediate certificate*) at the end of the certificate on the server:

```
cat /path/to/ica.crt >> /path/to/prosody.crt
```

Also see https://prosody.im/doc/certificates#certificate_chains for further information